# How can I get the geometry from a gltf object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have used three.js to get a gltf by gltfloader, and I want to create a particle system. I need to get the geometry object, how can I get it

```
function initModel() {

    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xaaaaaa, 
    side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
    plane.position.y = -.1;
    plane.receiveShadow = true; 
    scene.add(plane);

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('./../model/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {  
        gltf.scene.scale.set(10,10,10);
        //how to get the geometry?

    });


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse the model to find the mesh, or use getObjectByName(MeshName) when you know the name, and pick the geometry from the mesh.
Something like

```
var geometry = getObjectByName('Plane001').geometry;
```

if the name of the mesh is Plane001

I have a simple helper method to find all children of a type from an object

```
findType(object, type) {
    object.children.forEach((child) => {
        if (child.type === type) {
            console.log(child);
        }
        this.findType(child, type);
    });
}
```

from the loader I would then call `findType(gltf.scene, 'Mesh')` to print out all meshes in the model

Comment: It says getObjectByName is not defined

Comment: `this.findType(type,child)` does not work it referencing inside of the gltf class. Instead use `findType(type,child`) only.